# How to create a Keras face classifier between myself and others with a restrictive data set?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification

For the past 2 months I've been trying to create a classification model that can distinguish between myself and other people with Keras. I started from the dogs vs cats classifier and substituted the data set. Since then I have tweaked the network and the data set with some success. Also I have tried to augment my data set in many different combinations(flip, rotate, grayscale, lighten & darken the gamma; my augmentation turns 1 picture into 9).

For training I use my laptop's webcam to capture my face in different orientations and angles and I then split it in 3 (1/3 for validation and 2/3 for training). For the negative examples I have another data set of random people divided in the same way.

- validation:

  - person: 300
  - other: 300
- train:

  - person: 600
  - other: 600

To check my model I use some family photos on which I achieved around 80% accuracy but for this I only use 60 pictures, 36 of which are of myself.

```
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

print(train_generator.class_indices)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

print(validation_generator.class_indices)

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[tensorboard],
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save('model.h5')
```

All of my training attempts go pretty much the same way. First 1-2 epochs have close acc and loss values while the following ones jump to acc: 0.9 with loss: 0.1.

My assumption is that the problem is in the data set. What should I do in order to achieve a reasonable degree or accuracy by only using webcam taken photos?

Comment: What would be a reasonable degree of accuracy?

Comment: For CNN models, 1200 data points are too less. More the data, more will be the accuracy. Also, take your photos from different angles and incorporate "other" photos also taken from different angles, use data augmentation to increase data points.

Comment: I am hoping for over 90%. As it is right now, my model confuses me with other people that do not look all that similar to me and with a 30 year old woman of a different ethnicity while I am a white male

Comment: Most of my attempts consisted of the initial captured photos augmented. 1 picture turned into 9. Together, about 10800 photos. While taking photos with my webcam, I twist and turn in all possible ways. The "other" photos are from the internet but they are 1 photo-1 person.

Comment: Given the size of your dataset (small), you should consider transfer learning. You start with a trained network (like ResNet50 for instance), and you just re-train the last denses layers that do the prediction. If you want to use your custom network, train it on a large image dataset (faces if you can, or ImageNet) and then fine-train the Dense layers on your dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the amount of data you have, a better approach would be to use transfer learning instead of training from scratch. You can start with one of the pre-trained models for ImageNet like Resnet or Inception. But I suspect models trained on large face dataset may perform better. You can check the facenet implementation from [here](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet). You can train only the last fully connected layer weights and 'freeze' the earlier layers. How to classify using Facenet can be found [here](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/wiki/Classifier-training-of-inception-resnet-v1).